# Handling heavy processing within getView() method of a custom list adapter

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

My problem is simply that i have a custom ListView with custom Adapter .. in the Adapter getView() method i need some heavy processing to deduce the actual UI values ?

Which is making the scrolling horrible .. i'm using all the guide lines

Using recycled views .. Using ViewHolder design pattern

This processing isn't network operations or data retrieving 
they're just some loops and stuff 
How do i stop it from ruining my scrolling smoothness ?

Not sure if threading can be an answer since the UI values and handling are depending on the outcome of that processing ..

**EDIT**
I've taken care of the processing problem .. it's done in background now ..
My problem now is the listeners ..
I've an EditText and Spinner .. and they are initialized to a value rather than the default

the Listeners are firing too often that they're screwing with the scrolling ..

Comment: code code code... !!!

Answer (score 1):

First, you should never do heavy processing in UI thread method. Unfortunately, getView() is a typically UI thread method.

Second, use worker thread to do heavy processing, then refresh your item view when the processing is done.

Third, if you want to improve the scrolling performance further, stop refreshing UI when fling.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that's not where my problem is

Comment: could you elaborate a little concerning your last point ..
Does updating list cells from an AsyncTask cause the list to refresh ?
It's causing list to lag at scroll .. i do my processing in background .. and when i update ui in the OnPostExecute() .. it lags my scrolling

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/shelves/ You could find a class named BooksAdaper. It is a good example.

Comment: Thnx for the link .. but my case is kinda different ..
The processing is done fast .. not fast enough to be on UI thread
and not slow enough to allow UI to be painted then refreshed at low rate when finished
updates are too frequent that too many refreshes cause the scrolling to be slow and laggy